# C++17 Dictionary of names to any

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, any

I'm trying to create a dictionary in C++17 which associates a name to a pointer of any number of types simultaneously, and is able to deduce back the type on lookup without resorting to explicit casts on the caller side. These types can't be specified upfront in a variadic template.

The desired interface is the following:

```cpp
AnyDict<std::string, std::map> dict;

float num = 0.5f;
std::string str = {"Value"};

// If both inserts succeed this should evaluate to true.
if ( dict.insert("Hello"s, num) &&
     dict.insert("Other"s, str) )
    ; // ...

// This should return true.
dict.remove("Hello"s);

std::string def = {""};

// This should return a pointer to "Other", but
// if something goes wrong returns "".
auto* value = dict.find("Other"s, &def);
```

Currently my closest solution involves:

- Conversion of types to numbers

```cpp
// Currently I'm not using dlls or anything, but...
class TypeIdx
{
public:
    template <class Type>
    static int get()
    {
        // ugly.
        static const int s_idx = s_count++;

        return s_idx;    
    }

private:
    static inline int s_count = 0;
};
```

- A wrapper around a dictionary that encapsulates the conversion and the operations of the dictionary itself

```cpp
template <template <class, class> class Dict>
class AnyDict
{
public:
    // constructors, destructor, etc.

    template <class Type>
    bool
    insert(Type& item)
    {
        int key = TypeIdx::get<Type>();
        
        // The delegate must return true on success
        // or false on failure.
        return m_dict.insert(key, (void*) &item);
    }

    template <class Type>
    bool
    remove()
    {
        int key = TypeIdx::get<Type>();
        
        // The delegate must return true on success
        // or false on failure.
        return m_dict.remove(key);
    }

    template <class Type>
    Type*
    find(Type* def)
    {
        int key = TypeIdx::get<Type>();
        
        // The delegate must return a pointer to
        // the item found on success, or to "def"
        // on failure.
        return (Type*) m_dict.find(key, def);
    }

private:
    // Here the void* lets me save a pointer to
    // anything but i can't deduce back the type.
    Dict<int, void*> m_dict;
};
```

While this works and returns pointers of the correct type without casts, it still doesn't index them by name but by type, which is not what I'm looking for.

Do you know any solution? Maybe using `std::any` would improve the situation? Also if you could suggest a better name for this class it would be appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `std::any` here?  (Since it seems to be trying to re-invent `std::any`.)

Comment: It may help to give an example of what you would want the interface of your dictionary to look like.  Keep in mind that types can have any number of names (including 0).  Using something like [`std::type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) as your key type likely makes more sense than trying to use a type name or your existing home-rolled `TypeIdx`.

Comment: Should I edit the question?

Comment: @Giovanni Yes, editing your question is the best way to add additional information and clarifications.

Comment: Done. @Eljay I could use std::any, do you think it's the best solution? Any drawbacks?

Comment: The biggest drawback to `std::any` is inherent in what it does. C++ doesn't deal well with an object that could be anything, but `std::any` at least has many of the rough edges filed down.

Comment: I'm ignorant about pretty much any `std::` member, does it allocate memory dynamically?

Comment: Consider `if (rand() % 2 == 0) dict.insert("hello", 10); else dict.insert("hello", "ten"s);`.  What type should `dict.find("hello", "default"s)` return?  Should it return a `std::string`, since that's the default value's type?  Should it return the default value if the contained type doesn't match the default value?

Comment: _"does it allocate memory dynamically?"_ - By _"it"_ I suppose you mean `std::any`? If so, "it depends". Afaik, there is no rule but _"Implementations are encouraged to avoid dynamic allocations for small objects, but such an optimization may only be applied to types for which `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` returns `true`"_ (from [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any))

Comment: @MilesBudnek I didn't think about this problem. But after some research on `std::any`, I found that you still need to cast it back to the proper type manually, so casting a `void*` or a `std::any` is just a matter of rising errors at compile vs run time.

Comment: "cast it back to the proper type manually" Everything will need to do that. Each expression in C++ has a static type. `std::any` encapsulates any dynamic allocations it does, that's hugely preferable to `void *`

Comment: Real question is: what do you want to do with value for given key? Are you providing a type and name of a key to get this value? Or are you expecting to get type and value for particular key (this is impossible)? If you know what kind operation you need to do on returned value I'm pretty sure there is better way to solve this. What kind of functionality do you need which you think can be solved by `std::map<std::string, std::any>>`?

Comment: @Caleth I prefer to have control over the memory allocations outside the container and if everything needs a cast I can use a simple pointer. I can't predict the types of objects I will need to associate to their names so this container could be seen as a function of this form dict: (name, type) -> address.

Comment: That's a terrible reason. One of the strengths of C++ is that you can have deterministic release of resources without having to think about it. Humans are demonstrably terrible at repetitive tasks. You are causing bugs by not using the available tools

Comment: Yes, but currently I don't need such a strength. In the future may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `std::any` as the value type of your map, because it implements exactly the kind of type erasure that you need. No need to bother with scary void pointers. Here is a solution to get you started:

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>


template <typename key_type, template<typename, typename> typename Map>
class AnyDict
{
public:

    AnyDict() = default;

    template <typename value_type>
    bool insert(key_type const& k, value_type const& v) {
        auto [it, rt] = m_values.insert(std::make_pair(k, std::any{v}));
        return rt;
    }

    template <typename value_type>
    value_type find(key_type const& k, value_type const& default_value) const 
    {
        if (auto it = m_values.find(k); it != m_values.end()) {

            if (it->second.type() != typeid(value_type)){
                throw std::logic_error("type mismatch");
            }

            return std::any_cast<value_type>(it->second);
        }
        else {
            return default_value;
        }
    }

    bool remove(key_type const& k) {
        if (auto it = m_values.find(k); it != m_values.end()) {
            m_values.erase(k);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

private:

    Map<key_type, std::any> m_values;
};

int main()
{
    AnyDict<std::string, std::map> dict;

    // If both inserts succeed this should evaluate to true.
    if ( dict.insert(std::string {"Hello"}, 0.5f) &&
        dict.insert(std::string {"Other"}, std::string {"Value"}) )
    {
        std::cout << "Success.\n";
    }

    // This should return true.
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << dict.remove(std::string {"Hello"}) << "\n";

    // This should return "Other", but if
    // something goes wrong returns "".
    auto value = dict.find(std::string {"Other"}, std::string {""});
    std::cout << value << "\n";

};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GsrTE7975

Now I think there are some minor discrepancies between your desired interface and your question. For one, the desired interface doesn't store any pointers, but values, that is, according to the interface, the `dict` owns the values. The code above let's you store any type, *including*, but not limited to pointers: https://godbolt.org/z/sfhT68xK9

Comment: Your solution solves the problem so I will accept it; what you say about the interface is correct as well so I won't hesitate to fix it. I don't like the use of exceptions and all this `std::` functionality though, so I will post a solution that I like and will make everyone angry.

Comment: Is there a reason for `std::logic_error` over `std::bad_any_cast`?

Comment: @Caleth no there isn't. This is just a quick and dirty prototype. `std::bad_any_cast` is better. Still, the exception isn't thrown due to a failed `std::any_cast`, so IMHO it might even be better to define a custom exception for this kind of error. Since I don't know how OP wants do do error handling I didn't put too much effort into this part. I just wanted to point out that you need to deal with this situation somehow as pointed out in the comments by @MilesBudnek

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I like.

```cpp
template <class String, template <class, class> class Dict>
class AnyDict
{
public:
    // constructors, destructor, etc.

    template <class Type>
    bool
    insert(const String& name, Type& item)
    {
        return m_dict.insert(name, (void*) &item);
    }

    bool
    remove(const String& name)
    {
        return m_dict.remove(name);
    }

    template <class Type>
    Type*
    find(const String& name, Type* def)
    {
        void* addr = (void*) def;

        return (Type*) m_dict.find(name, addr);
    }

    template <class Type>
    Type*
    find(const String& name)
    {
        return (Type*) m_dict.find(name);
    }

private:
    Dict<String, void*> m_dict;
};
```

This doesn't solve the problem of the caller's responsibility on the type casts but **because** of this: there's no ambiguity on the return type. The casts will always be around even with `std::any` or with a completely different language.

```cpp
float def = 0.f;

auto* ptr = dict.find("Number"s, &def); // This is float thanks to "def".
auto* str = dict.find<std::string>("String"s, 0);
```

The usage is a bit inconvenient but for what I need this is enough.

Comment: This is a bit dangerous because of no type checking. What if you do `dict.insert("Number"s, "I am not a float");` and then `auto* ptr = dict.find("Number"s, &def)` afterwards? To enable type checking, you could store the `type_index` or `typeinfo` together with your `void*` pointer, but then again, why not use `std::any` directly? No need to use exceptions if you don't like them, use return values or something along the lines of `std::expected`.

Comment: I'm the type-checker (*chad.png*). Jokes aside, since I'm the only one who will use this container I can improve it in the future with type_info et simila, and nobody would get hurt in the meantime. I still prefer not to use `std::any` because with this code I'm sure nobody is allocating memory behind my shoulders and there's no need for custom allocators in this context.

Comment: In my personal experience, even if the code was written just for me, "future-me" will misuse the interface, fall into all pitfalls and will write buggy code, if I don't prevent him from doing so now. He can't be trusted.

Comment: In my personal experience what taught me the most were these risky ideas. I'm going to use this code in order to understand what's wrong and how to improve it.